# Flask giving 404 for static resources

Tags: python, flask

I'm sure this is easy, but I'm missing it.

The following flask template works, but gives 404 on the static files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Flask starter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello from template</h1>
        <script src="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the console output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2015 07:07:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2015 07:07:41] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2015 07:07:41] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2015 07:07:41] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is my project structure:

```
.
├── app
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── templates
|   │   └── index.html
|   └── views.py
└── static
    └── bower_components
        ├── bootstrap
        │   └── dist
        │       ├── css
        │       ├── fonts
        │       └── js
        └── jquery
            └── dist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just use `../static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js` this. `..` will direct to the root directory and same for other `href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static folder should be inside the app folder.

Static files can also be referenced like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```